# Can I write a loop to populate the dictionary with aggregate values for creating my table

Tags: django, database, loops, dictionary

I'm trying to call my transaction object and loop through it to create a dictionary of aggregate values from transaction object. I'm trying to populate a table with these values. Is it possible to do this and if so could I please get some advice. I want the dictionary to be populated with each distinct currency the user has transacted with, current amount of currency they own so sum(current_amount) for currency for user, purchase amount for currency for user sum(purchase_amount), sold amount per currency for usersum(sold), current value per currency for user,
purchase value per currency for user, and sold value per currency for user. I have data hard-coded right now for testing purposes but I want to make a loop to populate the json with results from a querie

Below table id like to populate

```
 {% for total_transaction in total_transactions %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{total_transaction.currency}}</td>
                <td>{{total_transaction.current_amount}}</td>
                <td>{{total_transaction.purchased_amount}}</td>
                <td>{{total_transaction.sold_amount}}</td>
                <td>{{total_transaction.current_value}}</td>
                <td>{{total_transaction.purchased_value}}</td>
                <td>{{total_transaction.sold_value}}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

function below

```
portfolio(request):

    count = Transaction.objects.filter(owner=request.user).values('currency').distinct(),

    context = {
        'total_transactions': [{
            'currency': 'BTC', 'current_amount': 3, 'purchased_amount': 5, 'sold_amount': 2, 'current_value': 180,
            'purchased_value': 400, 'sold_value': 380}, {
            'currency': 'LTC', 'current_amount': 3, 'purchased_amount': 5, 'sold_amount': 2, 'current_value': 180,
            'purchased_value': 400, 'sold_value': 380}, {
            'currency': 'XRP', 'current_amount': 3, 'purchased_amount': 5, 'sold_amount': 2, 'current_value': 180,
            'purchased_value': 400, 'sold_value': 380}
        ]
    }

    return render(request, 'webapp/portfolio.html', context, {'title': 'Portfolio'})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you Transaction model already contains all those fields you can simply use this:

```
portfolio(request):
    #define each sub query like this
    sum_currency_amount = Sum('amount').order_by('currency')
    #the main query will be to get all transaction per users following by each annotate that allows you to define some key and value for the queryset.
    transactions = Transaction.objects.filter(owner=request.user).annotate(
            currency_amount = sum_currency_amount,
            #other subquery here
    ),
    return render(request, 'webapp/portfolio.html', context, {'title': 'Portfolio','total_transactions':transactions})
```

The template can remain the same.

Comment: Hi @Ben i get this error when I try that. "'Sum' object has no attribute 'order_by'" do you have any idea why?